# Display Video or Images in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, video

I want to display Video/ Image in vb.net. Which control i have to use ? I have used the tag IFRAME but it only shows the swf file format. But I want to use control which shows all formats of video like what's app files. The control reads the path of the file from a database table.I have tried the following code.

**CODE OF ASPX FILE**

```
iframe ID="I1" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="100" name="I1" 
                  src='<%# Eval("FPATH") %>' width="160"> /iframe<
```

FPATH IS THE TABLE FIELD NAME

Comment: How to display video/image in vb.net linking path from database field. is there any control available. i am using IFRAME tag to display video/image but it only show youtube flash videos. plz help.